# jQuery - Show error on blank form fields on submit

Tags: jquery, html, validation, forms, field

I have an HTML form that puts an asterisk on each label when the user tries to submit it with fields left blank. However, it only puts an asterisk on the first label that is left blank, not all of them. Here's my HTML:

```
<label for="name"><span class="asterisk">* </span>Name</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="required" />

<label for="email"><span class="asterisk">* </span>Email</label>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="required" />

<label for="company"><span class="asterisk">* </span>Company</label>
<input type="text" id="company" name="company" class="required" />

<label for="address"><span class="asterisk">* </span>Address</label>
<input type="text" id="address" name="address" class="required" />

<label for="favColor"><span class="asterisk">* </span>Favorite Color</label>
<input type="text" id="favColor" name="favColor" value="N/A" />
```

And here's my jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.submit').click(function() {
    if ($('#name').val().length == 0) {
        $('label[for="name"] .asterisk').show();
        return false;
        }
    if ($('#email').val().length == 0) {
        $('label[for="email"] .asterisk').show();
        return false;
        }
    if ($('#company').val().length == 0) {
        $('label[for="company"] .asterisk').show();
            return false;
        }
    if ($('#address').val().length == 0) {
        $('label[for="address"] .asterisk').show();
        return false;
        }
    if ($('#favColor').val().length == 0) {
        $('label[for="favColor"] .asterisk').show();
        return false;
        }
    else {
        $('.right').stop().animate({scrollTop: 0}, { duration: 1500, easing: 'easeOutQuart'});
        }
    });
});
```

Please pardon the n00bish jQuery. If anyone can come up with a simple solution on how to make the asterisk in the span tags appear on all of the fields left blank on submit, that would be awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would give `#favColor` the `required` class since it is required, then do this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.submit').click(function() {
      $("label .asterisk").hide();
        var empty = $(".required").filter(function() { return !this.value; })
                                  .prev().find(".asterisk").show();
      if(empty.length) return false;   //uh oh, one was empty!
      $('.right').stop().animate({scrollTop: 0}, { duration: 1500, easing: 'easeOutQuart'});
    });
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/9Zhgf/).

Answer (score 2):

Since each required input has a `required` class, just select using that, and iterate over each one.

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/qeALK/

```
$('.submit').click(function() {
    var ret = true;
    $('.required').each(function() {
        if( !this.value ) {
            $(this).prev().children('.asterisk').show();
            ret = false;
        }
    });
    $('.right').stop().animate({scrollTop: 0}, { duration: 1500, easing: 'easeOutQuart'});
    return ret;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

add a single return or better yet use the [validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) plugin

```
$(function() {
    $('.submit').click(function() {
    var ret = true;
    if ($('#name').val().length == 0) {
        $('label[for="name"] .asterisk').show();
        ret = false;
        }
    if ($('#email').val().length == 0) {
        $('label[for="email"] .asterisk').show();
        ret = false;
        }
    if ($('#company').val().length == 0) {
        $('label[for="company"] .asterisk').show();
        ret = false;
        }
    if ($('#address').val().length == 0) {
        $('label[for="address"] .asterisk').show();
        ret = false;
        }
    if ($('#favColor').val().length == 0) {
        $('label[for="favColor"] .asterisk').show();
        ret = false;
        }
    else {
        $('.right').stop().animate({scrollTop: 0}, { duration: 1500, easing: 'easeOutQuart'});
        }
    return ret;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
$(function() {
$('.submit').click(function() {
var correct = true;
if ($('#name').val().length == 0) {
    $('label[for="name"] .asterisk').show();
    correct = false;
    }
if ($('#email').val().length == 0) {
    $('label[for="email"] .asterisk').show();
    correct = false;
    }
if ($('#company').val().length == 0) {
    $('label[for="company"] .asterisk').show();
    correct = false;
    }
if ($('#address').val().length == 0) {
    $('label[for="address"] .asterisk').show();
    correct = false;
    }
if ($('#favColor').val().length == 0) {
    $('label[for="favColor"] .asterisk').show();
    correct = false;
    }
if(correct == true) {
    $('.right').stop().animate({scrollTop: 0}, { duration: 1500, easing: 'easeOutQuart'});
    }else{
          return false;
    }
});
});
```

Actually the same code but with an correct variable.

Answer (score 1):

This could be better written like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.submit').click(function() {
        var ret = true;
        $('input.required').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                ret = false;
                $(this).prev().find('.asterisk').show();
            }
        });
        return ret;
    };
});
```